# missing sound-volume-applet

Tags: sound, applet

I am using ubuntu 12.10. I had some problems with my skype and audio. So I did the following and it's working fine now:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
```

After this I reinstalled pulseaudio via

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

But now my icon in the gnome-panel is missing. After searching on google I found that that the sound-volume-applet ist missing.

So is this right? And do you get the icon in the panel?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install the indicator-sound package which provides the normal ubuntu volumecontrol via the command

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

and to make the change take effect do

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: Thank you. People all around the internet say it's part of different packages, but nobody got it right but you :)

Comment: You are awesome

Comment: That solved one problem. But I still got no sounds

Comment: As an xfce user, this made my problem worse, now I have no panel at all.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another variant (how I solved this problem):
Go to dconf-editor (it's graphical settings editor for Gnmoe and Unity, maybe you need to install it first), there go to com->canonical->indicator->sound and check "visible". In my case it just turned to false after one update.

Steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. `dconf-editor`
3. com->canonical->indicator->sound and check `visible`

Comment: `In my case it just turned to false after one update.` - and in my case, it just turned false ... and I have no idea why! But no need to install packages, and this was the fix I needed.

Comment: For me the 'killall unity-panel-service' have not worked, but this one have worked properly.  The visible option was not checked. (12.04 LTS)

Answer (score 3):

If using gnome, must change last order:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound

killall gnome-panel
```

Works great!!