# Dell Latitude E5570 dummy soundcard

Tags: sound, dell

First, in my preinstalled **Ubuntu 14** there were sound devices visible but they were not giving out sound.

After a system resume from suspended state or sleep I received a dialog box asking if I have headphone or headset, I didn't plug in neither one.

I went on to upgrade to **Ubuntu 16** and from then on I had only **dummy sound card.**

Tested if there is a **hardware problem with Dell's** diagnostic tool that can be booted and from there I was able to get sound.

Went through myriads of forums, troubleshooters but without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reseted to factory default, with preinstalled OS, formated the drives and installed new Ubuntu, nothing seemed to help.

Even after doing this [troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) until steps 4 I didn't realized any advancement.

Interestingly when I gave it up and wanted to install a different OS, I tackled between UEFI and Legacy modes and had some failed booting attempts from my usb stick, so went back to my installed Ubuntu and viola I hear a startup sound!!!

This ubuntu was version 14 so I upgraded it to 16 and I still have the sound working!

Only that the sound indicator disappeared but I got it back easily by an [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/489495/634249).