# Dell Latitude E5570 headphone not working

Tags: 16.04, dell, headphones

To solve this issue it is really bothering me. The fixes that I saw and tried (there are many-...-many) are all just attempts, "hacks", no simple or bullet proof solution. [It was like a miracle that somehow my speakers started to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866452/dell-latitude-e5570-dummy-soundcard), now I would need another to get the headphone working.
There is a [similar question with Dell XPS 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789074/headphone-jack-not-working-with-dell-xps-13-bought-in-2014), neither did that solution work for me (I already have the dialog to choose between headset and headphone after I plug in my headset but no sound is coming out on it). Tried alsamixer to unmute, turn on volume on headphones/headset, no luck.

For related system info see the [launchpad question/bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/441890) that I have reported but seems to be quite there, didn't receive any response yet.

So this is all you can get with a Dell business class laptop that is certified for Ubuntu by Canonical?... Sad to say but I got disappointed in Ubuntu, Canonical. These problems with headphones are not dealt with priority, this was a problem 10 years ago and it is still. I need the headphones to watch courses/tutorials necessary for work... if I don't get a solution in a few weeks I will have to switch to Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that this is a driver issue and it just gets solved when the update comes for it...

After a few weeks probably because of a system update the headphone just started to work... and after a week it stopped working. Now when the headphone is not working I just switch the driver to no driver from the available drivers and now this usually does the trick (a month ago this didn't help).

**Interestingly enough, another thing that I have observed is that with the <kbd>microphone mute button</kbd> that is the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> the headphone gets muted/unmuted.**